# JackShmReadWritePtr Error in Pyttxs3 File

Tags: python, pyttsx

```py
import pyttsx3
engine = pyttsx3.init() # object creation

""" RATE"""
rate = engine.getProperty('rate')   # getting details of current speaking rate
print (rate)                        #printing current voice rate
engine.setProperty('rate', 125)     # setting up new voice rate


"""VOLUME"""
volume = engine.getProperty('volume')   #getting to know current volume level (min=0 and max=1)
print (volume)                          #printing current volume level
engine.setProperty('volume',1.0)    # setting up volume level  between 0 and 1

"""VOICE"""
voices = engine.getProperty('voices')       #getting details of current voice
#engine.setProperty('voice', voices[0].id)  #changing index, changes voices. o for male
engine.setProperty('voice', voices[1].id)   #changing index, changes voices. 1 for female

engine.say("Hello World!")
engine.say('My current speaking rate is ' + str(rate))
engine.runAndWait()
engine.stop()
```

I'm using the pyttsx3 library for a chatbot I'm making, and I ran this test on a separate file and now I'm getting an error...

```
200
1.0
ALSA lib pcm_dmix.c:1108:(snd_pcm_dmix_open) unable to open slave
ALSA lib pcm.c:2564:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.rear
ALSA lib pcm.c:2564:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.center_lfe
ALSA lib pcm.c:2564:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.side
ALSA lib pcm.c:2564:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.surround71
ALSA lib setup.c:547:(add_elem) Cannot obtain info for CTL elem (MIXER,'IEC958 Playback Default',0,0,0): No such file or directory
ALSA lib pcm.c:2564:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.hdmi
ALSA lib pcm.c:2564:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.hdmi
ALSA lib pcm.c:2564:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.modem
ALSA lib pcm.c:2564:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.modem
ALSA lib pcm.c:2564:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.phoneline
ALSA lib pcm.c:2564:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.phoneline
Expression 'alsa_snd_pcm_hw_params_set_period_size_near( pcm, hwParams, &alsaPeriodFrames, &dir )' failed in 'src/hostapi/alsa/pa_linux_alsa.c', line: 924
ALSA lib pcm_oss.c:377:(_snd_pcm_oss_open) Unknown field port
ALSA lib pcm_oss.c:377:(_snd_pcm_oss_open) Unknown field port
ALSA lib pulse.c:242:(pulse_connect) PulseAudio: Unable to connect: Connection refused

ALSA lib pulse.c:242:(pulse_connect) PulseAudio: Unable to connect: Connection refused

ALSA lib pcm_usb_stream.c:486:(_snd_pcm_usb_stream_open) Invalid type for card
ALSA lib pcm_usb_stream.c:486:(_snd_pcm_usb_stream_open) Invalid type for card
ALSA lib pcm_dmix.c:1108:(snd_pcm_dmix_open) unable to open slave
ALSA lib pcm_dmix.c:1108:(snd_pcm_dmix_open) unable to open slave
Expression 'parameters->channelCount <= maxChans' failed in 'src/hostapi/alsa/pa_linux_alsa.c', line: 1514
Expression 'ValidateParameters( outputParameters, hostApi, StreamDirection_Out )' failed in 'src/hostapi/alsa/pa_linux_alsa.c', line: 1846
Expression 'parameters->channelCount <= maxChans' failed in 'src/hostapi/alsa/pa_linux_alsa.c', line: 1514
Expression 'ValidateParameters( outputParameters, hostApi, StreamDirection_Out )' failed in 'src/hostapi/alsa/pa_linux_alsa.c', line: 1846
Expression 'parameters->channelCount <= maxChans' failed in 'src/hostapi/alsa/pa_linux_alsa.c', line: 1514
Expression 'ValidateParameters( outputParameters, hostApi, StreamDirection_Out )' failed in 'src/hostapi/alsa/pa_linux_alsa.c', line: 1846
Expression 'parameters->channelCount <= maxChans' failed in 'src/hostapi/alsa/pa_linux_alsa.c', line: 1514
Expression 'ValidateParameters( outputParameters, hostApi, StreamDirection_Out )' failed in 'src/hostapi/alsa/pa_linux_alsa.c', line: 1846
Expression 'parameters->channelCount <= maxChans' failed in 'src/hostapi/alsa/pa_linux_alsa.c', line: 1514
Expression 'ValidateParameters( outputParameters, hostApi, StreamDirection_Out )' failed in 'src/hostapi/alsa/pa_linux_alsa.c', line: 1846
Expression 'parameters->channelCount <= maxChans' failed in 'src/hostapi/alsa/pa_linux_alsa.c', line: 1514
Expression 'ValidateParameters( outputParameters, hostApi, StreamDirection_Out )' failed in 'src/hostapi/alsa/pa_linux_alsa.c', line: 1846
Expression 'parameters->channelCount <= maxChans' failed in 'src/hostapi/alsa/pa_linux_alsa.c', line: 1514
Expression 'ValidateParameters( outputParameters, hostApi, StreamDirection_Out )' failed in 'src/hostapi/alsa/pa_linux_alsa.c', line: 1846
wave_open_sound > Pa_OpenStream : err=-9996 (Invalid device)
wave_open_sound > Pa_OpenStream : err=-9996 (Invalid device)
wave_open_sound > Pa_OpenStream : err=-9996 (Invalid device)
wave_open_sound > Pa_OpenStream : err=-9996 (Invalid device)
wave_open_sound > Pa_OpenStream : err=-9996 (Invalid device)
wave_open_sound > Pa_OpenStream : err=-9996 (Invalid device)
wave_open_sound > Pa_OpenStream : err=-9996 (Invalid device)
wave_open_sound > Pa_OpenStream : err=-9996 (Invalid device)
wave_open_sound > Pa_OpenStream : err=-9996 (Invalid device)
wave_open_sound > Pa_OpenStream : err=-9996 (Invalid device)
wave_open_sound > Pa_OpenStream : err=-9996 (Invalid device)
wave_open_sound > Pa_OpenStream : err=-9996 (Invalid device)
wave_open_sound > Pa_OpenStream : err=-9996 (Invalid device)
wave_open_sound > Pa_OpenStream : err=-9996 (Invalid device)
wave_open_sound > Pa_OpenStream : err=-9996 (Invalid device)
wave_open_sound > Pa_OpenStream : err=-9996 (Invalid device)
wave_open_sound > Pa_OpenStream : err=-9996 (Invalid device)
wave_open_sound > Pa_OpenStream : err=-9996 (Invalid device)
wave_open_sound > Pa_OpenStream : err=-9996 (Invalid device)
wave_open_sound > Pa_OpenStream : err=-9996 (Invalid device)
wave_open_sound > Pa_OpenStream : err=-9996 (Invalid device)
wave_open_sound > Pa_OpenStream : err=-9996 (Invalid device)
wave_open_sound > Pa_OpenStream : err=-9996 (Invalid device)
wave_open_sound > Pa_OpenStream : err=-9996 (Invalid device)
wave_open_sound > Pa_OpenStream : err=-9996 (Invalid device)
wave_open_sound > Pa_OpenStream : err=-9996 (Invalid device)
wave_open_sound > Pa_OpenStream : err=-9996 (Invalid device)
wave_open_sound > Pa_OpenStream : err=-9996 (Invalid device)
wave_open_sound > Pa_OpenStream : err=-9996 (Invalid device)
wave_open_sound > Pa_OpenStream : err=-9996 (Invalid device)
wave_open_sound > Pa_OpenStream : err=-9996 (Invalid device)
```

I researched on how to fix it, but I couldn't understand what everyone was saying, so how do I fix this? Thanks!
.......................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................(this was to go against me not being able to post that much code without many words)

Comment: Are you on Linux?

Comment: @Lukasz Tracewski Yes I’m on Ubuntu

Comment: @KrishPatel ***"how do I fix this?"***: This is not a `python` or `pyttsx` issue. Delete this question and ask at [askubuntu.com](https://askubuntu.com/)

Answer (score 1):

The error indicates that there's a problem with `jack server`. For starter, I'd try to restart audio system and see if it works:

```
pulseaudio --kill  
jack_control start
jack_control exit  
pulseaudio --start
```

If `jackd` won't just die, `kill` it.

Comment: @KrishPatel Stupid question, but can you play sound without issues? Also, please list audio devices `lspci -knn|grep -iA2 audio`